# Error Test in IntelliJ (sbt-shell): java.net.URISyntaxException

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, uri

I am trying to run a test in my scale code in Intellij.
I run this command from sbt shell in IntelliJ

```
test:testOnly *PixellingWorkflowSpec
```

and see this error:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Users\ENRICO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\test_dir3179226687891855242/hive_test_app_78705/thrift
```

I can't run the test. How can I solve it? Why does this error come out?

Comment: Are you using a SBT plugin which compiles your thrift definitions? What is the contents of the file / directory mentioned in the error message?

Comment: yes , I'm using SBT plugin and run from sbt-shell

Comment: Does it work when you run the same command in `sbt` directly or is it IntelliJ specific?